# Referring to other figures from within a chunk

Tags: r, latex, knitr, bibtex

Inside the plot generated in a chunk in a knitr/LaTeX document I want to position a text string with a reference to a particular figure elsehwere in the document, something like "See Fig. 10", based on the label of a that particular figure, lets say "fig:sim1".  So I wrote the following R function which reads the .aux file of the LaTeX-document I'm writing and extracts the counter of the figure matching a specific label

```
ref <- function(label) {
  lines <- scan("mismatch-final.aux","character",sep="\n")
  line <- grep(paste("\\{",label,"\\}",sep=""),lines,value=TRUE)
  strsplit(strsplit(line,"\\{\\{")[[1]][2],"\\}\\{")[[1]][1]
}
```

I can then generate the desired text string from within the chunk and place it inside the plot with something like

```
text(5,10,paste("See Fig.~",ref("fig:sim1")))
```

This should work but perhaps there is a cleaner way of doing this? Also, is there a way to get at the .aux filename from within the chunk such that the ref function above would be made more general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do that is to use the **tikzDevice** package and TikZ plots, so you can write raw LaTeX expressions in your plot, e.g

```
\begin{figure}
....
\caption{Simulation of something. \label{fig:sim1}}
\end{figure}

<<test, dev='tikz', external=FALSE>>=
plot(rnorm(10), rnorm(10))
text(0, 0, 'See Fig \\ref{fig:sim1}')
@
```

Depending on the complexity of your plot, this chunk may take a few seconds to compile each time. The plot is saved as a LaTeX file, and any LaTeX commands will work in it.

Comment: The journal need all figures in pdf, eps or tiff format. I believe a pdf version of the figure is generated if I set external=TRUE which is then included with \includegraphics{ } from the latex file produced if I'm not mistaken?  But with external=TRUE the figure is compiled independently from the rest of the document so that the label would be unavailable, wouldn't it?  So I think I'll go for the solution based on reading the aux file with R code from within the chunk.

Comment: @user2768086 That makes sense. Personally I'd just hard-code the figure number in the plot unless I have a large number of figures in the paper. Actually I'd put the reference in the figure caption instead of the R plot. It is not worth it to do too much work to gain just a little...